# I just upgraded to 13.04 and Samba isn't working. It is installed but will not open. Any help?

Tags: samba

So I just upgraded to 13.04. I had to do a fresh install because I was having problems updating from 12.04, so I lost all of my previous settings and programs.

Now that 13.04 is up and running, I immediately installed Samba as it is how I stream my media to my WDTV Live.

The software center says that Samba has successfully installed and it appears in my dock, but when I click it it does not open. When I restart my computer Samba disappears from my dock and it cannot be found on my computer (by searching in unity). I then have to go to the software center, uninstall Samba and reinstall it in order to get it to appear in my dock again. Of course, the problem persists.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Changed comment to answer...
    vvv

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Here is the solution that worked for me.

NOTE: If you have tried the installation and it doesn't work go to the Software Center and *uninstall* Samba first.

1. Open Terminal
2. Install `gksu`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```
3. In the terminal, run

   ```
   gksu-properties
   ```

   In the dialogue that follows set authentication mode to "sudo" and grab mode to "enable".
4. Install Samba:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
   ```
5. Install Samba Config:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install samba system-config-samba cifs-utils
   ```

   The Samba icon showed up on the launch bar and everything worked fine.

I take no credit for this solution it is a compilation of my frustration and others hard work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure Samba is a service rather than an application. Try installing Samba and using "File" (Nautilus) to access the network share. You may have to adjust the Samba settings but it generally worked for me out of the box (albeit in previous editions). In "File" you should specify a url like `servername://Share_name/directory`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but managed to fix it. It is happening because gksu is not installed in 13.04 by default, and dash presumably tries to run `gksu system-config-samba`, and does not find gksu.

To install gksu, open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Then type:

```
gksu-properties
```

In the dialogue that follows set *authentication mode* to "sudo" and *grab mode* to "enable".