# Samba is not working on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, samba

I tried installing samba from Ubuntu Software Centre and [from](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/) command line after installing .

When I tried opening it is now showing in the application launcher or now working through command line.
[image: From Terminal]
[image: From App Launcer]

Any help

Comment: Which file did you install?

Comment: samba doesn't work that way.. Try if it's running using smbstatus.. It probably won't give you much because you haven't configured it yet. smbd --version will print te current version of your install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is the solution that worked for me.

NOTE: If you have tried the installation and it doesn't uninstall Samba, Samba-common, system-config-samba first. to do it just replace "install" with "remove" in steps 3 & 4

Open Terminal

1. Install gksu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```
2. In the terminal, run

   ```
   gksu-properties
   ```

   In the dialogue that follows set authentication mode to "sudo" and grab mode to "enable".
3. Install Samba:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
   ```
4. Install Samba Config:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install samba system-config-samba cifs-utils
   ```

The Samba icon showed up on the launch bar and everything worked fine.

I take no credit for this solution this answer is form "user168736" answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288229/i-just-upgraded-to-13-04-and-samba-isnt-working-it-is-installed-but-will-not-o)

Answer (score 1):

As Bart.a points out, samba doesn't work that way. The package called `samba`|`samba4` just provide the modules and tools to allow applications connect trough the CIFS protocol to NetBIOS implementations. But, lets quote the Wikipedia article:

> Samba is a free software re-implementation of the SMB/CIFS networking protocol, originally developed by Andrew Tridgell. As of version 3, Samba provides file and print services for various Microsoft Windows clients and can integrate with a Windows Server domain, either as a Primary Domain Controller (PDC) or as a domain member. It can also be part of an Active Directory domain.

Meaning, `samba` isn't an application with a GUI, but a module/service to *nix systems.

The samba client is mostly manageable with the defaults file browsers (Nautilus, Konqueror, etc...), with little or none configuration. To check all the SMB/CIFS resources available in your network, just typing `network://` normally should show the results. For sharing files/devices/resources you need the samba-server, which is too configurable using the tools provided by Gnome, KDE, Unity without problems.

There are plenty of tools that allows you to browse your resources, [graphically control your samba client/server here](http://www.samba.org/samba/GUI/), some of them already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not install all the packages you need. I think you can use the command-line version, but you're looking for the GUI one, right? Please try the following. Found that [here](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/)

Install samba:

`sudo apt-get  install  samba samba-common`

Install dependencies for the tools:

`sudo apt-get install python-glade2`

Install the GUI samba tools:

`sudo apt-get install system-config-samba`

Add a samba user:

`adduser yourname`

Specify a user password:

`passwd yourname`

Now you can look up the samba tool in unity and start configuring your shares.
In the link you can also find a description on how to make shares.

Good luck. And if you can't get it to work, come back here to the forum.

Comment: I did the same . Please go though my question first

Comment: maybe there is another problem. When you have installed all of the above and it still doesn't work. Try this in the terminal: sudo apt-get install gksu - then run: gksu-properties - a pop-up should appear and set authentication mode to "sudo" and grab mode to "enable"